# Does anyone know what the heck this is?

Tags: rf, siemens

I really hope I'm posting this in the right section.

I was strolling down the street and looked up at this massive barrel object mounted to a utility pole.  It's hard to tell from the pic, but it definitely has the brand **Siemens** stuck to its side.  Being Siemens, I figured the electrical engineering section deemed worthy.  Everything else was illegible due to its height above the sidewalk.  There's what looks like a huge RF antenna poking out of the bottom of it.

I'm hoping that someone who does line work or know RF or something might know what this is?

[image: What the heck is this thing??]

Comment: The barrel looks like a very large capacitor about to explode.

Comment: Did you happen to notice your mobile phone signal strength while you were near it?

Comment: It's the gov'n'ment reading your thoughts! Better wear a tinfoil hat! ;)

Comment: Knowing the country where you saw it may give people some more hints for its identification. To me it seems (wild guess) like some kind of pollutants detection/measuring system with remote wireless connection to a central control station. The box on the left may be its transformer/power supply unit.

Comment: Or a barrel for measuring rain level with a transmitter :)

Comment: If there are connections to a HV line then I could make a guess. But for now. No idea.

Comment: It's a bit bucket. It collects all those extra internet requests that get lost when IE hangs.

Comment: the box is unlocked, so just turn it off and see what kind of truck comes out to turn it back on.

Comment: The white "stick" underneath must be explained by any hypothesis, I think. It appears to have an opening intended to avoid rain or falling particulates but to allow access to the air. A sensor probe of some kind. Pitot stasis tube came first to mind, but now I'm wondering about radiation detection. It's normal to have a certain well-specified rate of air flow through a filter that is periodically removed and analyzed for particulates. And Seimens would have experience in this area. Being next to a power line would not interfere and might just be a convenience. In Europe, may make sense.

Comment: >LorenzoDonati It's in Toronto, Canada.
>Decapod I don't think it's connected to the HV line, its probably stepped down to 230V
>dandavis hahah, good one.
@jonk Probably the best explanation.  I even went as far as to check Siemens website and could not find any product that matches the looks of this one.  Shall remain a mystery I suppose?

Comment: Do you have "Broadband Over Power Lines" there? That is my guess.

Comment: @nocomprende no we don't

Comment: It could as easily be a smart meter hub.